# Combining overlapping date ranges without using a cross join in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, self-join, gaps-and-islands, correlated-subquery, cross-join

If I have this dataset:

```
create schema if not exists dbo;
create table if not exists dbo.player_history(team_id INT, player_id INT, active_from TIMESTAMP, active_to TIMESTAMP);
truncate table dbo.player_history;
INSERT INTO dbo.player_history VALUES(1,1,'2020-01-01', '2020-01-08');
INSERT INTO dbo.player_history VALUES(1,2,'2020-06-01', '2020-09-08');
INSERT INTO dbo.player_history VALUES(1,3,'2020-06-10', '2020-10-01');
INSERT INTO dbo.player_history VALUES(1,4,'2020-02-01', '2020-02-15');
INSERT INTO dbo.player_history VALUES(1,5,'2021-01-01', '2021-01-08');
INSERT INTO dbo.player_history VALUES(1,6,'2021-01-02', '2022-06-08');
INSERT INTO dbo.player_history VALUES(1,7,'2021-01-03', '2021-06-08');
INSERT INTO dbo.player_history VALUES(1,8,'2021-01-04', '2021-06-08');
INSERT INTO dbo.player_history VALUES(1,9,'2020-01-02', '2021-02-05');
INSERT INTO dbo.player_history VALUES(1,10,'2020-10-01', '2021-04-08');
INSERT INTO dbo.player_history VALUES(1,11,'2020-11-01', '2021-05-08');
```

and I want to get combine overlapping date ranges, so that I can identify 'islands' where at least one player was active. Then I can do a cross-join and a correlated subquery to get the results as such:

```
with data_set as (
SELECT 
    a.team_id
    , a.active_from
    , ARRAY_AGG(b.active_to ORDER BY b.active_to DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS active_to
FROM dbo.player_history a
LEFT JOIN dbo.player_history b
    on a.team_id = b.team_id
where a.active_from between b.active_from and b.active_to
group by 1,2
)

select team_id
    , min(active_from) as active_from
    , active_to
from data_set
group by 1,3
order by active_from, active_to
```

and this gives me the desired results, however with larger data set this approach is not feasible, and BigQuery does not recommend doing joins in such a manner. Looking at the execution plan its mostly the join which causes the slowness. Are there any ways to achieve the desired output in a more efficient way?

Comment: For 100k rows your query works, but takes several minutes (10 minutes runtime, over 20 minutes slot time). Is there a limit of players per team? Or what is the maximum number? How many teams are there in total?

Comment: Get the start points of intervals. (Taking care to not be off-by-1. Typically, characterize intervals via 1 closed & 1 open endpoint.) Split every non-empty interval that has one inside via an iterative/recursive cte. PS This is surely a faq. But (as before considering posting any question) you need to google (with 'site:stackoverflow.com') for many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [partitioned table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#:%7E:text=A%20partitioned%20table%20is%20a,bytes%20read%20by%20a%20query.) to get better performance with large amounts of information. The partitioned tables divide a large table into smaller partitions, thus you can improve query performance. The partitioned tables are based on a TIMESTAMP, DATE, or DATETIME .

An option could be:

1. Create a partitioned table
2. Load the data in the partitioned table
3. Execute the query

You can see this example:

With this query, you are creating a partitioned table and load the data at the same time. Maybe it takes some time the first time you load the data only, but it’ll be much faster when you access the partitioned table.

```
CREATE TABLE
  mydataset.newtable (transaction_id INT64, transaction_date DATE)
PARTITION BY
  transaction_date
AS SELECT transaction_id, transaction_date FROM mydataset.mytable
```

Then execute the query

```
SELECT transaction_id, transaction_date FROM mydataset.newtable
Where transaction_date between start_date and finish_date
```

There are some [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results#cache-exceptions) using a partitioned table because it uses the results saved on cache.

Also, you can see this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-compute) about some points you need to consider to get the best performance when you create a query.

Comment: Since the join is based on two columns start & end time then I'm not sure I can get the benefits of partitioning?

Comment: You can use [integer range parttitioned](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#integer_range)

Answer (score 0):

A very fast query to obtain for each team a list of time periodes with at least one player active:

```
create temporary function test(a array<date>,b array<date>)
returns array<struct<a date,b date>>
language js
as """
var out=[];
var start=a[0];
var end=a[0];
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
if(a[i]<=end) {if(end<b[i]) end=b[i]}
else {
    var tmp={"a":start,"b":end};
    out.push(tmp);
    start=a[i];
    end=b[i];
 }
}
out.push({"a":start,"b":end});

return out;
""";

select team_id, test(array_agg(active_from order by active_from),array_agg(active_to order by active_from))
from 
 dbo.player_history
 group by 1
```

Your result shows:
[image]
It is confusing to show that the start date is within the previous time segment.

If your player are only active for a few years in average this query gives a a list of all dates on which a team consist of only one player or less.

```
with tbl_lst as (
Select team_id,date_diff(active_to,active_from,day),
generate_date_array(active_from, active_to, INTERVAL 1 DAY) as day_list
from dbo.player_history )
SELECT team_id,day,sum(active_players) as active_players
FROM (
SELECT team_id,day,count(1) as active_players
from tbl_lst,unnest(tbl_lst.day_list) as day
group by 1,2
Union ALL 
Select team_id, day,0 from
(Select team_id,min(active_from) as team_START,max(active_from) as team_END 
from dbo.player_history
group by 1),
unnest(generate_date_array(team_START, team_END, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) day
)
group by 1,2
having active_players<2
```

This following query needs 16 stages and is slow, but obtains for every time interval the amount of active players. Two tables are joined and the table `data_set` are only the dates in the interval, therefore it can be a maximum of 3650 rows for 10 years.

```
#generate a list of all dates
with dates as (
SELECT active_from as start_date from dbo.player_history 
Union ALL SELECT active_to  from dbo.player_history 
#Union ALL Select timestamp("2050-01-01")
),
# add next date to this list
data_set as ( 
SELECT Distinct start_date, lead(start_date) over (order by start_date) as end_date
from dates
order by 1
)

# count player at each time
Select team_id, start_date,end_date,
count(player_id) as active_player,
string_agg(cast(player_id as string)) as player_list

from dbo.player_history 
RIGHT JOIN
data_Set
on active_from<=start_date and active_to>=end_date
group by 1,2,3
having active_player<2
order by start_date
```

Comment: Hi Samuel, my phrasing might have been confusing. I'm interested in identifying the periods where at least one player is active. The output of my query is correct, but not able execute on a team of 100k players.